# FLEX java.home PATH backslashes

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript

I've writed in my config.jvm:

```
java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jre6
```

but when i write in my console mxmlc.exe it gives me an error:

```
Error loading: C:/Program Files/Java/jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

it adds a backslashes to the path automatically, but if i write the full path to the jvm.dll like this:

```
java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/server
```

it gives me an error:

```
Could not find a JVM
```

what can I do?

I am on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](http://www.qlambda.com/2010/07/mxmlc-error-loading-filesjavajre6binser.html), you need to use the 32-bit JRE in `Program Files (x86)` (whereas the one in `Program Files` is 64-bit). So:

```
java.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6
```

Comment: but if my machine is 64x? or you mean 86x java?

Comment: @Hello: Yes. This answer presupposes that your machine *is* 64-bit, since if it were 32-bit, you would not need to do anything special to use the 32-bit JRE.

Comment: I see there http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html only 64x AND 86x for windows, it looks like i need x86 java?